How to properly determine if an Bitlocker encrypted disk has a corrupted partition table?
Background: A Bitlocker encrypted hard disk (5TB WD Elements HDD USB) was accidentally wiped partially using the wiping tool Eraser Classic Portable (using the US DoD 7 passes method).  The wiping only went on for a few minutes (max. 5 min) before the mistake was noticed and the wiping action stopped. Likely because of this the first sectors of the disk were wiped. The disk is physically fine.
No partition are recognized anymore using diskpart and the Windows Disk Management tool prompts to initialize the disk as MBR or GPT. Based on this, my estimation is that the partition table is corrupted. I know it is possible to use repair tools to repair Bitlocker such as repaid-bde, however I doubt that will work when the partitions can't even be identified. Also, the Bitlocker password is known but the recovery key has yet to be identified, see: How to identify a GUID of a corrupted Bitlocker disk in order to find the corresponding Bitlocker recovery key?
Is a corrupted partition table the correct conclusion based on above information? Secondly, if all this background information was not known, how would I be able to determine if the disk used Bitlocker at all, and especially how to conclusively determine if the partition table of the disk is in tact or corrupted?

The moment you started the wipe you lost the required data to decrypt your data. As encrypted data is essentially random data, there is no effective means of data recovery, on an encrypted drive. Even if you could recover the partition table, you would be unable to decrypt, any of the data on the partitions. repair-bde isn’t applicable to your situation. If the disk wasn’t encrypted, recover the partitions using the appropriate data recovery tools, and scan the recovered partition with the appropriate data recovery tools.
